# Undefined State when pulling data for mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pulling data from my my database which needs to be available prior to the mounting of the component in order for the page to be populated with the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. I've verified that if i remove the setState and console.log my data, it does fetch from the DB as expected, but when I try to assign the data to my state variable, it return a error stating `Unable to get property 'setState' of undefined or null reference` within my `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method. I've listed my ReactJS code below.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Picture from '../../components/picture.jsx';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
export default class Products extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {clothingData: ''};
    }

    componentWillMount(){
            fetch('/t')
            .then(function(result){
              return result.json();
            })
            .then(function(re){
              this.setState({ clothingData: re });
              console.log(this.state.clothingData);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        //empty for now
    }

    render(){
        var MyArray = ['justin','tiffany','joe','john','karissa','pam','joseph','sean','kim'];
        var imageSrc = ['http://placehold.it/249x373','http://placehold.it/249x373','http://placehold.it/249x373','http://placehold.it/249x373','http://placehold.it/249x373',
                        'http://placehold.it/249x373', 'http://placehold.it/249x373', 'http://placehold.it/249x373']; 

    return (
      <div>
        <Picture src = {imageSrc} onClick = { () => {browserHistory.push('/Product'); }} name = {MyArray} amount = {8} />
      </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is being reassigned from the component instance to the function instance/global object.

```
componentWillMount() {
  fetch('/t')
    .then((result) => {
      return result.json();
    })
    .then((re) => {
      this.setState({ clothingData: re });
      console.log(this.state.clothingData);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

will work just fine since the arrow function will ensure that the `this` is bound to the component instance so `this.setState` will actually be defined. Whereas what you have the `this` is being set to the global object which does not have a property of `setState`

Comment: Thanks ! I knew my code was on the right track, and I thought that by using a react lifecycle method that it would inherit "this", so I didn't even think twice about it. Thanks